# How to get the Jenkins master IP/hostname inside a pipeline stage executing on a slave?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a Jenkins declarative pipeline in which I build in one stage and test in another, on different machines. I also have a Selenium hub running on the same machine as the Jenkins master.

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      agent { node { label 'builder' } }
      steps {
        sh 'build-the-app'
        stash(name: 'app', includes: 'outputs')
      }
    }
    stage('Test’) {
      agent { node { label 'tester' } }
      steps {
        unstash 'app'
        sh 'test-the-app'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like for the Selenium tests that run on at the Test stage to connect back to the Selenium hub on the Jenkins master machine, and that means that I need to get the IP address or hostname of the Jenkins master machine from the slave.

Is there a way to do this? The Jenkins master URL / hostname isn't in the environment variables and I'm uncertain how else to get the Jenkins master's IP address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if there are better ways to do this, I am able to run

```
def masterIP = InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress
println "Master located at ${masterIP}"
```

in my Jenkinsfile. The first time I ran this code in my Jenkinsfile, the build failed with

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: 
Scripts not permitted to use method java.net.InetAddress getHostAddress
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:178)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor$6.reject(SandboxInterceptor.java:243)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:363)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
```

I had to approve the method signature in Jenkins by navigating to `Manage Jenkins` > `In-process Script Approval`.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired from @kayvee for using BUILD_URL, the following worked from me:

```
def getJenkinsMaster() {
    return env.BUILD_URL.split('/')[2].split(':')[0]
}
```

This returns the master's hostname or IP as it would appear in the build URL. If you also require the port number remove the second `split()`.

Comment: This won't work if Jenkins runs behind a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 4):

To get current slave host :

```
Jenkins.getInstance().getComputer(env['NODE_NAME']).getHostName()
```

To get master host :

```
Jenkins.getInstance().getComputer('').getHostName()
```

Comment: this will probably return the container id if you're running jenkins in docker

Comment: I confirm, this does return the docker hostname

Comment: Why master computer is called '' (empty string)???

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this way:

```
 stage("SomeStageName") {
     agent { label 'exampleRunOnlyOnLinuxNode' }
     steps {
         script {
              println "\n\n-- Running on machine: " + "hostname".execute().text
         }
     }
 }
```

and `"hostname -i".execute().text` will print the IP

Answer (score 0):

Try this below shell command

```
def host= sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo ${BUILD_URL/https:\\/\\/} | cut -d "/" -f1').trim()
println("Hostname : ${host}")
```