# How to run Jenkins parallel cypress on different agents?

Tags: docker, jenkins, testing, frontend, cypress

I'm running parallel cypress in Jenkins on the same slave, and it's working,

I want to change the parallel stages so each stage will run on a different slave, how can I do it?

for example:

run "cypress tester A" on slave-1.

run "cypress tester B" on slave-2.

run "cypress tester C" on slave-3.

this is my current Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
options {
    timeout(time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES')
}
agent {
    docker {
        image 'cypress/base:12.18.2'
        label 'slave-1'
    }
}
parameters {
    string(defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Branch name', name: 'branchName')
}

stages {
    stage('build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Running build...'
            sh 'npm ci'
            sh 'npm run cy:verify'
        }
    }

    stage('cypress parallel tests') {
        environment {
            CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY = 'MY_CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY'
            CYPRESS_trashAssetsBeforeRuns = 'false'
        }
        parallel {
            stage('cypress tester A') {
                steps {
                    echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
                    sh "npm run cypress:run"
                }
            }
            stage('cypress tester B') {
                steps {
                    echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
                    sh "npm run cypress:run"
                }
            }
            stage('cypress tester C') {
                steps {
                    echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
                    sh "npm run cypress:run"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

post {
    always {
        cleanWs(deleteDirs: true)
        echo 'Tests are finished'
    }
}
```

}

The `cypress:run` command is:

```
cypress run --record --parallel --config videoUploadOnPasses=false --ci-build-id $BUILD_TAG
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by explicityly defining the `agent` within each parallel stage:

```java
parallel {
    stage('cypress tester A') {
        agent {
            node: {
                label "slave-1"
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
            sh "npm run cypress:run"
        }
    }
    stage('cypress tester B') {
        agent {
            node: {
                label "slave-2"
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
            sh "npm run cypress:run"
        }
    }
    stage('cypress tester C') {
        agent {
            node: {
                label "slave-3"
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
            sh "npm run cypress:run"
        }
    }
}
```

However, one disadvantage I found is now that you're running cypress in each individual node/virtual machine, cypress needs to know where to find the running instance of your application.  Cypress looks into cypress.json at `baseUrl` to see where to find your app.  Its common to use a localhost address for development, which means cypress runnning on slave-1 will look for an app running on localhost of slave-1 - but there isn't one, so it will fail.

For simplicity's sake, I just did an `npm install` and `npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000` in each node:

```java
stage('cypress tester A') {
    agent {
        node: {
            label "slave-1"
        }
    }
    steps {
        echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
        sh "npm install --silent"
        sh "npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000"
        sh "npm run cypress:run"
    }
}
```

This is obviously not very efficient because you have to install and run the app on each node.  However, you could potentially set up a previous stage on a dedicated node (say, slave-0) to install and serve your project, and use that.  Within your Jenkinsfile, you'll need to know the IP of that slave-0, or you could [get it dynamically within your Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578971/how-to-get-the-jenkins-master-ip-hostname-inside-a-pipeline-stage-executing-on-a).  Then instead of installing and running your project on slave-1, 2 and 3, you would install and run it just on slave-0, and use the `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` env variable to tell cypress where to find the running instance of your app.  If the IP of slave-0 is 2222.2222.2222.2222, you might try something like this:

```java
pipeline {
    stage ('Serve your project'){
       agent {
           label 'slave-0'
       }
       steps {
           sh 'npm install --silent'
           sh 'npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000'
       }
    }
    stage('Cypress'){
        environment {
            CYPRESS_BASE_URL=2222.2222.2222.2222:3000
            // other env vars
        }
        parallel {
            stage {
               agent {
                   label 'slave-1'
               }
               steps {
                   echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
                   sh "npm run cypress:run"
               }
            }
            // more parallel stages
        }
    }
}
```

There's a lot of variations you can do, but hopefully that will get you started.