# How to run Cypress tests in parallel using a single machine on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress, parallel-testing

So I have around 45 spec files that I want to execute in parallel on a single machine on Jenkins.

If I create a freestyle job on Jenkins and run this command "npx cypress run --record --key abc --parallel" it executes sequentially.

Do I need to set up nodes on Jenkins, in order to do parallel execution using this command? I am not able to find how exactly I can do that and I have tried various configurations but it still runs sequentially despite the "--parallel"

How do I specify how many threads I can execute it on? Or is that decided automatically by the number of machines? In my case, I can only do this using my single machine and local Jenkins.

Creating a pipeline and passing parallel{} in the stage as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013383/how-to-run-jenkins-parallel-cypress-on-different-agents) is not working either so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Can someone please share a sample pipeline format for parallel Cypress test execution along with a guide to how nodes are created on Jenkins? Please tell me what additional steps I need to do as well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will have to execute multiple cypress runners in order for Cypress to actually run in parallel. If you only have one `npx cypress run` command, then only one runner is being used.

I've found the easiest way to run multiple cypress runners is to use [`npm-run-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all).

Assuming my script in my `package.json` is `cypress-tests`, my `npm-run-all` script to run the tests with three runners would be:

```bash
npm-run-all cypress-tests cypress-tests cypress-tests --parallel
```

Note: the `--parallel` flag here tells `npm-run-all` to run your commands in parallel. If the corresponding cypress flag is removed, your tests will not run in parallel (instead, `npm-run-all` will run two cypress runners in parallel, but each running your entire suite.)

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I specify how many runners/threads I want? Means how will I tell that I want the tests to be divided in 2 or 3 or 4 for parallel?

Comment: You have to specifically start the runners. Cypress does not control _how_ many runners you have running, only orchestrating what tests each runner gets. I'll update my answer to be clearer.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for me. It's executing the files in sequential manner

Comment: Do you have a cypress director that is controlling the execution? Running Cypress in parallel requires a director to assign out tests for each runner to execute. By default, this is your Cypress dashboard account.